# Spring cloud stream Confluent KStream Avro Consume

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to consume confluent avro message from kafka topic as Kstream with spring boot 2.0.

I was able to consume the message as `MessageChannel` but not as `KStream`.

```
@Input(ORGANIZATION)
KStream<String, Organization> organizationMessageChannel();


@StreamListener
    public void processOrganization(@Input(KstreamBinding.ORGANIZATION)KStream<String, Organization> organization) {
        log.info("Organization Received:" + organization);
 }
```

**Exception:**

> Exception in thread
>   "pcs-7bb7b444-044d-41bb-945d-450c902337ff-StreamThread-3"
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: stream-thread
>   [pcs-7bb7b444-044d-41bb-945d-450c902337ff-StreamThread-3] Failed to
>   rebalance.    at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:860)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:808)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744)
>   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to
>   configure value serde class
>   io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde  at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.defaultValueSerde(StreamsConfig.java:859)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.(AbstractProcessorContext.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.(ProcessorContextImpl.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.(StreamTask.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask(StreamThread.java:404)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask(StreamThread.java:365)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$AbstractTaskCreator.createTasks(StreamThread.java:350)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addStreamTasks(TaskManager.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.createTasks(TaskManager.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$RebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamThread.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:367)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1146)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1111)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:851)
>     ... 3 more Caused by: io.confluent.common.config.ConfigException:
>   Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no
>   default value.    at
>   io.confluent.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:243)    at
>   io.confluent.common.config.AbstractConfig.(AbstractConfig.java:78)
>     at
>   io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.java:61)
>     at
>   io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.java:32)
>     at
>   io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.configure(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:48)
>     at
>   io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.configure(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:58)
>     at
>   io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde.configure(SpecificAvroSerde.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.defaultValueSerde(StreamsConfig.java:855)
>     ... 19 more

Based on the error I think I'm missing to configure the `schema.registry.url` for confluent. 
I had a quick look at the sample [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/schema-registry-samples/kafka-streams-schema-evolution/kafka-streams-confluent-consumer/src/main/java/sample/consumer/CountVersionApplication.java#L56) 
Kind of bit lost on how to do the same with spring cloud stream using the `streamListener`

Does this need to be a separate configuration? or Is there a way to configure `schema.registry.url` in `application.yml` itself that confluent is looking for?

here is the code repo https://github.com/naveenpop/springboot-kstream-confluent

**Organization.avsc**

```
{
   "namespace":"com.test.demo.avro",
   "type":"record",
   "name":"Organization",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"orgId",
         "type":"string",
         "default":"null"
      },
      {
         "name":"orgName",
         "type":"string",
         "default":"null"
      },
      {
         "name":"orgType",
         "type":"string",
         "default":"null"
      },
      {
         "name":"parentOrgId",
         "type":"string",
         "default":"null"
      }
   ]
}
```

**DemokstreamApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
@Slf4j
public class DemokstreamApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemokstreamApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public  static class organizationProducer implements ApplicationRunner {

        @Autowired
        private KafkaProducer kafkaProducer;

        @Override
        public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
            log.info("Starting: Run method");
            List<String> names = Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "green", "black", "white");
            List<String> pages = Arrays.asList("whiskey", "wine", "rum", "jin", "beer");
            Runnable runnable = () -> {
                String rPage = pages.get(new Random().nextInt(pages.size()));
                String rName = names.get(new Random().nextInt(names.size()));

                try {
                    this.kafkaProducer.produceOrganization(rPage, rName, "PARENT", "111");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.info("Exception :" +e);
                }
            };
            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable ,1 ,1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

**KafkaConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value("${spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint}")
    private String endpoint;

    @Bean
    public SchemaRegistryClient confluentSchemaRegistryClient() {
        ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient client = new ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient();
        client.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        return client;
    }

}
```

**KafkaConsumer.java**

```
@Slf4j
@EnableBinding(KstreamBinding.class)
public class KafkaConsumer {

   @StreamListener
    public void processOrganization(@Input(KstreamBinding.ORGANIZATION_INPUT) KStream<String, Organization> organization) {
        organization.foreach((s, organization1) -> log.info("KStream Organization Received:" + organization1));
    }
}
```

**KafkaProducer.java**

```
@EnableBinding(KstreamBinding.class)
public class KafkaProducer {

    @Autowired
    private KstreamBinding kstreamBinding;

    public void produceOrganization(String orgId, String orgName, String orgType, String parentOrgId) {

        try {
            Organization organization = Organization.newBuilder()
                    .setOrgId(orgId)
                    .setOrgName(orgName)
                    .setOrgType(orgType)
                    .setParentOrgId(parentOrgId)
                    .build();

            kstreamBinding.organizationOutputMessageChannel()
                            .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(organization)
                            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, orgName)
                            .build());

        } catch (Exception e){
            log.error("Failed to produce Organization Message:" +e);
        }
    }
}
```

**KstreamBinding.java**

```
public interface KstreamBinding {

    String ORGANIZATION_INPUT= "organizationInput";
    String ORGANIZATION_OUTPUT= "organizationOutput";

    @Input(ORGANIZATION_INPUT)
    KStream<String, Organization> organizationInputMessageChannel();

    @Output(ORGANIZATION_OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel organizationOutputMessageChannel();
}
```

**Update 1:**

I applied the suggestion from dturanski [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59034832/2199826) and the error vanished. However still not able to consume the message as `KStream<String, Organization>` no error in the console.

**Update 2:**

Applied the suggestion from sobychacko [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59075830/2199826) and the message is consumable with empty values in the object.

I've made a [commit](https://github.com/naveenpop/springboot-kstream-confluent/commit/6e42cd279e6c7733b9f4b2552469c6ce2f08c509) to the GitHub sample to produce the message from spring boot itself and still getting it as empty values.

Thanks for your time on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following implementation will not do what you are intending:

```
@StreamListener
    public void processOrganization(@Input(KstreamBinding.ORGANIZATION)KStream<String, Organization> organization) {
        log.info("Organization Received:" + organization);
 }
```

That log statement is only invoked once at the bootstrap phase. In order for this to work, you need to invoke some operations on the received `KStream` and then provide the logic there. For e.g. following works where I am providing a lambda expression on the `foreach` method call.

```
 @StreamListener
    public void processOrganization(@Input(KstreamBinding.ORGANIZATION) KStream<String, Organization> organization) {

        organization.foreach((s, organization1) -> log.info("Organization Received:" + organization1));
    }
```

You also have an issue in the configuration where you are wrongly assigning avro `Serde` for keys where it is actually a `String`. Change it like this:

```
default:
                key:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                value:
                  serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
```

With these changes, I get the logging statement each time I send something to the topic. However, there is a problem in your sending groovy script, I am not getting any actual data from your `Organization` domain, but I will let you figure that out.

#### Update on the issue with the empty `Organization` domain object

This happens because you have a mixed mode of serialization strategies going on. You are using Spring Cloud Stream's avro message converters on the producer side but on the Kafka Streams processor, using the Confluent avro Serdes. I just tried with the Confluent's serializers all the way from producers to processor and I was able to see the `Organization` domain on the outbound. Here is the modified configuration to make the serialization consistent.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: kstream
  cloud:
    stream:
      schemaRegistryClient:
        endpoint: http://localhost:8081
      schema:
        avro:
          schema-locations: classpath:avro/Organization.avsc
      bindings:
        organizationInput:
          destination: organization-updates
          group: demokstream.org
          consumer:
            useNativeDecoding: true
        organizationOutput:
          destination: organization-updates
          producer:
            useNativeEncoding: true
      kafka:
        bindings:
          organizationOutput:
            producer:
              configuration:
                key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
                value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
                schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
        streams:
          binder:
            brokers: localhost
            configuration:
              schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
              commit:
                interval:
                  ms: 1000
              default:
                key:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                value:
                  serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
```

You can also remove the `KafkaConfig` class as wells as the `EnableSchemaRegistryClient` annotation from the main application class.

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this. I think the empty object problem is not with groovy and it seems to be somewhere else. I tried to produce the message from spring boot itself with the same GitHub sample and getting the same empty object. here is the commit https://github.com/naveenpop/springboot-kstream-confluent/commit/6e42cd279e6c7733b9f4b2552469c6ce2f08c509

Comment: I updated the answer. Please try to make those changes and see if it resolves your issues.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes the provided updated solution works. Using the below property worked. `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.organizationInput.consumer.useNativeDecoding = true 
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.organizationOutput.producer.useNativeEncoding = true`

Comment: I wish this was in documentation on in the wiki

Answer (score 1):

Try `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.schema.registry.url: ...`

Comment: Thanks dturanski. I see the error vanished. However, I'm not able to consume the messages as `KStream<String, Object>` and no error is reported.

Comment: Could you simplify that sample to just one processor? and some instructions for reproducing the issue. I am also wondering if you could upgrade to the latest release (`3.0.0.RELEASE`) of the binder and try again.

Comment: I've simplified the sample application to have one processor and also added the instructions in the readme here https://github.com/naveenpop/springboot-kstream-confluent/blob/master/Readme.md Also, as you suggested i tried to upgrade to the latest `3.0.0.RELEASE` and received failed to introspect class captured that in the same read me.

Comment: when you say upgrade to `3.0.0.RELEASE` i think i may need to upgrade the spring boot too, isn't it? Just checking if this is not possible to have it working in Spring boot `2.0.0.RELEASE` itself. Thank you!